# Android Create an app which already exist but without delete it

Tags: android, signed

For the context I work on AndroidStudio 1.2 and I don't use the androidMarket.

The problem is that I'm trying to install an app (which I improve) on some phone where there is an version of the app(some student have already work on it).

I have this message "App not installed, an existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed."

I know that this question has already been asked but the answer don't match with my problem. Because I don't want to uninstall the previous app but have the two versions on the phone.

Also, I have tried to change the package name, the name of the app and the signed but nothing seems to work...

I would like to thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Changing the project name in manifest file doesn't work?? Let me know if it works.

Comment: Actually I create a new package move everythin in it and then delete the old one and also change the package in the manifest file. But it doesn"t work.

Comment: This is not the right way to do that. You should import your project as module.

Comment: What  happened? I am not getting you

Comment: I had imported the module (like you said) and then change package name in the manifest, build graddle and in the projectview by using change directory.

Comment: Then accept it as answer or upvote. So that others can get exact idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the right way to do that. You should import your project as module.